# NSComboBox items misplaced if user drag an app window on mac OS

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, combobox

I work at desktop application for OS X and macOS and have issue with native NSComboBox (**not subclass**).

It is the problem that comboBox items misplaces as you can see on screenshot below.

[image: NSComboBox items misplaced]

Also a have a warning in XCode console output:

> This application is trying to draw a very large combo box, 28 points tall.  Vertically resizable combo boxes are not supported, but it happens that 10.4 and previous drew something that looked kind of sort of okay.  The art in 10.5 does not break up in a way that supports that drawing.  This application should be revised to stop using large combo boxes.  This warning will appear once per app launch.

Could this be a warning associated with this problem? I tried to fix warning but failed.
I use Xcode 8.2.1 and OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

**Edited:**

Current ViewController contained in **custom navigation controller** and have combobox delegate/datasource implementation.

View added as below to navigation container:

```
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    viewController.view.frame.size = contentView != nil ? contentView!.frame.size : CGSize.zero
    viewController.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.viewWidthSizable, .viewHeightSizable]

    if let animation = animation {
        contentView?.layer?.add(animation, forKey: animation.type)
    }
    contentView?.addSubview(viewController.view)
```

ComboBox datasource implementation

```
    public func numberOfItems(in comboBox: NSComboBox) -> Int {

    switch comboBox {
    case companyComboBox:
        return filteredCompanies?.count ?? 0
    case projectComboBox:
        return filteredProjects?.count ?? 0
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

public func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, objectValueForItemAt index: Int) -> Any? {

    switch comboBox {
    case companyComboBox:
        return company(at: index)?.name
    case projectComboBox:
        return project(at: index)?.name
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

public func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, indexOfItemWithStringValue string: String) -> Int {

    switch comboBox {
    case companyComboBox:
        return selectedCompany == nil ? -1 : comboBox.indexOfSelectedItem
    case projectComboBox:
        return selectedProject == nil ? -1 : comboBox.indexOfSelectedItem
    default:
        return -1
    }
}

public func comboBox(_ comboBox: NSComboBox, completedString string: String) -> String? {

    switch comboBox {
    case companyComboBox: 
        let bestMatched = bestMatchedCompany(for: string)
        filteredCompanies = filterCompanies(by: string)
        return bestMatched?.name

    case projectComboBox:
        let bestMatched = bestMatchedProject(for: string)
        filteredProjects = filterProjects(by: string)
        return bestMatched?.name

    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

ComboBox delegate implementation:

```
    //MARK: NSComboBoxDelegate

func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

    let comboBox = notification.object as! NSComboBox
    let selectedIndex = comboBox.indexOfSelectedItem

    guard selectedIndex >= 0 else { return }

    switch comboBox {
    case companyComboBox:
        selectedCompany = company(at: selectedIndex)
    case projectComboBox:
        selectedProject = project(at: selectedIndex)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {

    guard let comboBox = control as? NSComboBox, comboBox.stringValue.characters.count > 0 else { return false }

    if (commandSelector == #selector(insertBacktab(_:))) {

        switch comboBox {
        case companyComboBox:
            filteredCompanies = filterCompanies(by: comboBox.stringValue)
        case projectComboBox:
            filteredProjects = filterProjects(by: comboBox.stringValue)
        default:
            break
        }

    } else if commandSelector == #selector(deleteBackward(_:)) {

        //Need to filter by substring of comboBox.stringValue because before deleteBackward comboBox has old text value.

        let selectedTextRange = textView.selectedRanges.first as! NSRange

        let endIndex = comboBox.stringValue.index(comboBox.stringValue.startIndex,
                                                  offsetBy: selectedTextRange.length > 0 ? selectedTextRange.location : selectedTextRange.location - 1)

        let filterValue = comboBox.stringValue.substring(with: comboBox.stringValue.startIndex..<endIndex)

        switch comboBox {
        case companyComboBox:
            filteredCompanies = filterCompanies(by: filterValue)
        case projectComboBox:
            filteredProjects = filterProjects(by: filterValue)
        default:
            break
        }

    } else if commandSelector == #selector(insertNewline(_:)) || commandSelector == #selector(insertTab(_:))  {

        switch comboBox {
        case companyComboBox:
            let company = bestMatchedCompany(for: comboBox.stringValue)
            if comboBox.stringValue == company?.name {
                selectedCompany = company
            }
        case projectComboBox:
            let project = bestMatchedProject(for: comboBox.stringValue)
            if comboBox.stringValue == project?.name {
                selectedProject = project
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is this an old Xcode project? Is this a subclass of NSComboBox? Did you implement any of the delegate methods?

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Is anything logged to the console?

Comment: Console output: "This application is trying to draw a very large combo box, 28 points tall. Vertically resizable combo boxes are not supported, but it happens that 10.4 and previous drew something that looked kind of sort of okay. The art in 10.5 does not break up in a way that supports that drawing. This application should be revised to stop using large combo boxes. This warning will appear once per app launch." But I'm not sure that this is related to my problem.

Comment: The warning could be autolayout related. The misplaced items problem looks like an exception. What happens when you temporarily simplify the datasource and delegate and only implement `numberOfItemsInComboBox` and `objectValueForItemAtIndex`?